# Could not resolve AutosuggestEngine in Here map Sdk

Tags: android, here-api

I am using Here map sdk in my android application. In one of the case I want to use Auto search for places. To achieve this I used "AutosuggestEngine", but it is showing error "Could not be resolved".

I found the code in the following link.
[Link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk/dev_guide/topics/search.html#places-search)

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Just to be sure: you refer to HERER SDK 4.x Lite Edition and this is the version you are using in your app, yes ? Could you please verify ? It's a quite new release and product overall, so just wanted to be sure you don't talk about MobileSDK 3.x and mixed up the docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to HERER SDK 4.x Lite Edition and use the latest version.

> developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html#create-a-new-android-project